Pip only installing dependencies, not main package
I have made a previous package that I put in https://gitlab.com/Matthijs.Kramer/common (I don't think it's public, it's work-related) that contains the following pyproject.toml:
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools >= 61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "common"
version = "2024.7.1"
dependencies = [
    "geopandas==0.14.3",
    "JayDeBeApi==1.2.3",
    "numpy==1.26.4",
    "oauthlib==3.2.2",
    "pandas==2.2.1",
    "psycopg2-binary==2.9.9",
    "PyMySQL==1.1.0",
    "Requests==2.31.0",
    "requests_oauthlib==1.3.1",
    "SQLAlchemy==2.0.25",
    "urllib3==1.26.18"
]
description = "Common functionality for ..."
readme = "README.md"
requires-python = ">=3.9"
classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3"
]

I have another very simple project that has this package above as a dependency, so I wanted to create a new venv with this package included. So I did pip install git+https://gitlab.com/Matthijs.Kramer/common.git and a bunch of packages started installing into my venv. Now, all my dependencies of the common packages are installed, but the common package itself is not. Doing python -c "import common" leads to a ModuleNotFoundError, and there is no common directory in site-packages.
I want the common package to also be installed into site-packages. This can easily be done by manually git cloning it into site-packages, but I figure there must be a way to have this done with pyproject.toml and pip.
